# How to Access Office 365 Calendar If Someone granted permission to access calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps

I granted permission to the app that is registered with Microsoft to access the calendar. 
Now I want that app to access my calendar.

How it is possible with Micorsoft Graph to access calendar any time if access is granted? 
What should be steps to consume MS graph API in this case?

Also can we have a non-expiry token?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to access the calendar any time when someone have granted permission to access calendar.

We can configure application permissions for your app. Then anyone don't need granted the permission and they can access calendar. For doing this, we can use a background services or daemons that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user.

> Also can we have a non-expiry token?

I think there may not a non-expiry token, however we can refresh the accesstoken before it expired.